# Yii CDbCommand запрос большого количества данных и memory

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii, memory

Необходимо выгрести большое кол-во данных из базы данных и положить в Excel так, чтобы по пути не закончилась память.

Сейчас память заканчивается в месте:

```
$command->query();
```

Насколько я знаю query() возвращает CDbDataReader, чтобы можно было получать по одной строчке, а не весь массив разом.

Я предполагал, что при таком подходе весь результат запроса не будет храниться в памяти, но она заканчивается.

Есть вариант сделать метод, который будет вытаскивать по 100 записей пока не закончится таблица.

Есть ли вариант обойтись без дополнительных методов, а получать и хранить в памяти по 1 строчке?

Наткнулся на такой вот пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895098/pdo-mysql-memory-consumption-with-large-result-set

Можно ли это сделать с CDbCommand?

Как бы вы решили такую задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Код из документации:

```
$dataReader=$command->query();

// многократно вызываем read() до возврата методом значения false
while(($row=$dataReader->read())!==false) { … }
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.dao#sec-4

Comment: Но память переполняется в момент $dataReader=$command->query();